# Directing Users to One of Random pages when page load

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I am building an HTML web application but I need a little help. I have it linked to a launch page. But this is the part that I need help with, how can I redirect users to different pages. Say I had the following pages as random redirects:

b/b1.html
b/b2.html
b/b3.html
b/b4.html
b/b5.html

I want the user to get directed to just **one** of those. I know how to insert a standard html redirect.

I would appreciate it if any of you had any code samples. Thanks

Comment: Put the URLs in an array in JavaScript and select a random element from the array, then redirect the user to that URL in JavaScript.

Comment: Please never put "solved" or similar into the title.  "Accepting" an answer below is the only permissible way to indicate the question was solved.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This very quick solution the urls variable is just a space separated array which can be any url, if you need it to be absoulute instead of relative put in the full url including the https://blah.com part

```
var urls='b/b1.html b/b2.html b/b3.html b/b4.html b/b5.html'.split(' ')
window.location=urls[Math.floor(Math.random()*urls.length)]
```

Comment: Oh OK. That makes more scene. Thanks